# Handling NULL values in Hive

Tags: null, hive

I am trying to create a table (table 2) in Hive from another table (table 1). I am trying to exclude certain rows with NULL values and tried the following condition.

```
    insert overwrite table table2 partition (date = '2013-06-01')
    select column1, column 2....
    from table1
    where column1 is not NULL or column1 <> '';
```

However, when I try this following query with the new table I get 300+ rows with NULL vaues:

```
    select count(*) from table2 where column1 is NULL;
```

Could someone point to what is causing these NULL values?

Thank you.

Ravi

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Firstly — I don't think `column1 is not NULL or column1 <> ''` makes very much sense. Maybe you meant to write `column1 is not NULL and column1 <> ''` (`AND` instead of `OR`)?

Secondly — because of Hive's "schema on read" approach to table definitions, invalid values will be converted to `NULL` when you read from them. So, for example, if `table1.column1` is of type `STRING` and `table2.column1` is of type `INT`, then I don't think that `table1.column1 IS NOT NULL` is enough to guarantee that `table2.column1 IS NOT NULL`. (I'm not sure about this, though.)

Comment: Definitely, it's **AND**. The column must not be NULL AND must not be empty (''). Ruakh gave the good answer.

Comment: Does it mean that we always need post-filtering for the output table because invalid values can emerge?

Answer (score 8):

Try to include length > 0 as well.

```
column1 is not NULL AND column1 <> '' AND length(column1) > 0
```

Comment: why should we include length(column1) > 0  along with column1 <> '' ?

Answer (score 2):

What is the datatype for column1 in your Hive table? Please note that if your column is STRING it won't be having a NULL value even though your external file does not have any data for that column.

Answer (score 1):

Try using isnull(a), isnotnull(a), nvl(), etc. On some versions(potentially in conjunction with the server settings - atleast with the one I am working on) of hive the 'IS NULL' and 'IS NOT NULL' syntax does not execute the logic when it is compiled. Check  [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)  for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To check for the **NULL** data for column1 and consider your datatype of it is String, you could use below command :

```
select * from tbl_name where column1 is null or column1 <> '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I use below sql to exclude the null string and empty string lines.

```
select * from table where length(nvl(column1,0))>0
```

Because, the length of empty string is 0.

```
select length('');
+-----------+--+
| length()  |
+-----------+--+
| 0         |
+-----------+--+
```

Comment: Above query discards only `''` values . If value is `null` then above query will return 0, for which length is 1.